# how to convert a json data to a url parameter

Tags: java, json, url, curl, data-conversion

I have the following curl command

`{"auth": {"tenantName": "demo", "passwordCredentials": {"username": "demo", "password": "password"}}}`

Since this is declared as a body, hence we have to send it as a url parameter in java.

So how to write this as a url parameter.

For example `{"username": "demo", "password": "password"}` would become something like `username=demo & password=password`

How to convert it in case of my requirement?

Comment: To clarify, you wish to do this conversion in a Java environment?

Comment: yes, but i dont have to write a parser for the same. it has to be hard coded. the requirement here is very specific.

Answer (score 0):

You can make "flat" (one-level) submissions using regular forms using this kind of technique:

You can use Apache's URIBuilder for that in Java:

http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/client/utils/URIBuilder.html

If you want to do it in JavaScript instead there is an example here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Forms/Sending_forms_through_JavaScript

"Building an XMLHttpRequest manually" section.

But your first example has "nested" structure; that is, there is a JSON hash within a JSON hash.

That is the problem with the nested "auth" and "passwordCredentials" keys.  They are no longer directly translatable as regular form parameters so you have to make something up.  There are common conventions for it however.

Regular web forms do not support this kind of multilevel tree structure.  Therefore you would need to use a different kind of encoding.  The simplest way to put it in a GET parameter is to hardcode a top-level parameter called, for example 'json' and then just throw the entire JSON string in there with URL escaping.  So for your example this would look like:

{"auth": {"tenantName": "demo", "passwordCredentials": {"username": "demo", "password": "password"}}}
becomes

json=%7B%3Aauth%3D%3E%7B%3AtenantName%3D%3E%22demo%22%2C+%3ApasswordCredentials%3D%3E%7B%3Ausername%3D%3E%22demo%22%2C+%3Apassword%3D%3E%22password%22%7D%7D%7D

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestion, but i just need a hard coded result for the same. I just need to know what would the result of the given json body be when converted to url parameter.

Comment: Hello,thanks a lot but I need to pass the data in the form of a post. So in Java it would be something like String urlParam = "<the text here>" and then I eould convert it into a byte array and write it to the outputStream

Comment: You said "url parameter" in the original question.  You can post that kind of string too (www form encoded) or you can send a "raw post".